# How can someone determine from the surface current distribution the electric field polarization?

Tags: antenna, radiation

How someone can determine by looking at the surface current direction what e-field components to expect? For example only \$E_\theta\$ or only \$E_\phi\$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Great question! The answer has to do with the boundary conditions of Maxwell's Equations at interfaces.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields

Time varying surface current at an interface create a time varying magnetic field, which create a time varying electric field.

If the surface currents are constant, then you get a magnetic field but no electric field.

The magnetic field will be perpendicular to and in the same plane as the surface current. The electric field will be perpendicular to the magnetic field (essentially aligned with the surface current).

Comment: Well this is what I thought initially, that the e-field follows the direction of Jsurf. However, I am a bit confused with a patch antenna simulated in CST. The Jsurf is towards direction of x-axis, perpendicular to the patch surface. Then we get a significantly larger \$E_\phi \$ component compared to \$E_\theta \$. Why is that?

Comment: @bigboss That's a good question too. Here's some explanation https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_explain_the_current_distribution_of_simple_rectangle_patch_antenna the E component comes from the time varying H component and the direction of propagation. I assumed a dipole and that propagation was normal to the current. Patch antennas propagate differently, so the e-direction is different! All the different sections in a patch antenna contribute to that